# How to track which user or arn has done DynamoDB data-plane operations on a specific table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have an AWS dynamodb table. I'm able to use DynamoDB streams to track changes to the records but I'm not able to see any information about the user that has updated the records in my table (not the table)? Need to know the details like logged-in user id or ARN of the AWS services which has updated the records in the table.

Using this to find the changes to the records in the table: https://nickolasfisher.com/blog/DynamoDB-Streams-and-Python-A-Working-Introduction

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by enable **DynamoDB data events** in CloudTrial:

- [Logging DynamoDB Operations by Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html)